# Keras neural network predicting the same output

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I need to develop a neural network with Keras to predict a disease using genetic data. It is known, that predicting this disease is possible even with logistic regression (however the predictions, in this case, are of very poor quality). It's worth mentioning that my data is imbalanced, so I introduced class weights later.

I decided to start with the simplest way to predict it - with a network, analogous to a logistic regression - one hidden layer with one neuron and achieved a bad, yet at least some result - 0.12-0.14 F1 score. Then I tried with 2 hidden and 1 output layers with different amount of neurons in the first hidden layer - from 1 to 8.
It turns out that in some cases it learns something, and in some is predicting the same output for every sample. I displayed the accuracy and loss function over the epochs and this is what I get:

[Network loss function by epoch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YNSC.png). It's clear that the loss function has roughly the same value, for the training data.

[Network accuracy by epoch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pozG3.png). It's clear that the accuracy is not improving, but fluctuates from 0 to 1

I searched for similar questions and the suggestions were the following:

1. Make more neurons - I just have to make it work with 1, 2 or more neurons in the first layer, so I can't add neurons to this one. I increased the amount of neurons in the second hidden layer up to 20, but it then stopped predicting anything with any number oh neurons in the first layer configuration.
2. Make more layers - I tried adding one more layer, but still have the same problem
3. To introduce dropout and increase it - what dropout are we talking about if it can learn with just one layer and one neuron in it
4. Reduce learning rate - decreased it from the default 10^(-3) to 10^(-4)
5. Reduce batch size - varied it from 500 samples in a minibatch to 1 (stochastic gradient descent)
6. More epochs - isn't 20 to 50 epochs on a 500'000 sample dataset enough?

Here's the model:

```
    
def run_nn_class_weights(data, labels, model):
    n_iter = 20
    predicted = None
    true = None

    print('Splitting the data')
    x_train, x_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(data, labels, test_size = 0.05)

    #model = create_model()
    early_stopping_monitor=EarlyStopping(patience=240)
    class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced',
                                             np.unique(labels),
                                             labels)

    class_weights = dict(enumerate(class_weights))

    hist = model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=[x_valid, y_valid], class_weight=class_weights, 
                            epochs=n_iter, batch_size=500, shuffle=True, callbacks=[early_stopping_monitor],verbose=1)


    proba = model.predict(data)
    predicted = proba.flatten()
    true = labels

    return(model, proba, hist)


def old_model_n_pred(n_neurons_1st = 1):
    model = Sequential()
    
    model.add(Dense(n_neurons_1st, activation='relu', input_shape=(7516,), kernel_initializer='glorot_normal'))
    model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    
    #model.add(Flatten())
    
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='adam',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

Comment: Has your dataset been normalised?

Comment: There's something wrong with your labels. Is the test data only one class? Your accuracy is jumping from 0 to 100 and back to 0 every epoch

Answer (score 0):

This is a small network that should be able to converge to something that's not an atractor (getting stuck on a single value).

I suggest taking a look at the weights of all the neurons with ReLu activation.
ReLus are great because get quick calculations; but half of the relu has derivate of zero, which doesn't help with gradient descent. This might be your case.

In guess in yout case the enemy would be the first neuron.

In order to overcome this problem, I would try to do regularize inputs (to have all samples centered around 0.5 and scaled by the standard deviation). If you do this to a ReLU, you'll make it ignore anything under between [-inf, sd].

*if* that does not fix *part* of the problem, swich to a different activation function in the first layer. A sigmoid will work very good and it's not too expensive for just one neuron.

Also, take a close look at your input distribution. What your network actually does is doing a sigmoid-like classification, then using between 4 to 8 neurons to "zoom"/correct on the important parts of the function that the first transformation didn't account for.